# How to install specific release of a package

Tags: centos, rhel, yum

I have to deal with some specific custom in-house repository for yum. I want to be able to install the lastest *tagged* version of my package. Repo at the same time contains hundreds of different snapshot version of packages and algo tagged, release versions.  You can tell the difference by doing yum info on a specifiv version, e.g.

`yum info mypkg-0.18.0-1`

This returns

`Available Packages
Name        : mypkg
Arch        : noarch
Version     : 0.18.0
Release     : 1
Size        : 25 k
Repo        : in-house-repo
Summary     : My package summary
URL         : http://example.com
License     : Proprietary
Description : sample description`

I can tell the difference between tagged and snapshotted version only by looking at the Release field.

- if Release is 1, then the version is tagged and ready for production
- if Release is 0.0.x, then this is a snapshot version of the package

What I want to do is to automatically install the latest tagged version of my script, which means the highest version found with the Release field set to 1.

Is there a way to do this without some dirty scripts parsing output with `grep`?

Comment: One idea would be to create a separate yum repo containing production rpms, another containing snapshots.  Can then do stuff like `yum --disablerepo=snapshotrepo install mypkg`.  You've also the option of not even presenting snapshotrepo to your production estate.

Comment: Yup I agree with this, problem is right now (for at least ~month) I have no way to enforce my company to change their repo handling policy :(

Comment: Ouch.  Thought about writing a yum plugin, or seeing if the existing 'versionlock' plugin could help ?  https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/centos-redhat-fedora-yum-lock-package-version-command/

Comment: Hmm... come to think of it, I can probably make it work with `versionlock` and proper regexp. Will try later today, thanks for the tip!